# CGBitmapContextGetData returning nothing?

Tags: ios, core-graphics

I have some CGImageRef called originalFrame full of data. Using it, I want to do the following:

- Make the image grayscale
- Rotate the image
- Crop the image
- Feed the resultant pixel data to an external library

However, when I do so, the pixel buffer is just *completely empty*, no matter what I do:

```
 // Convert to grayscale, translate, rotate, crop.
    CGColorSpaceRef graySpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
    uint8_t *croppedData = (uint8_t *)malloc( sizeof(uint32_t)*CROPPED_WIDTH*CROPPED_HEIGHT );
    memset( croppedData, 0, sizeof(uint32_t)*CROPPED_WIDTH*CROPPED_HEIGHT );

    context = CGBitmapContextCreate( croppedData, CROPPED_WIDTH, CROPPED_HEIGHT, 8, height*sizeof(uint32_t), graySpace,  kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst );
    CGContextClipToRect(context, CGRectMake( 0, 0,  CROPPED_WIDTH, CROPPED_HEIGHT ) );
    CGContextTranslateCTM( context, 0, width );
    CGContextRotateCTM( context, -M_PI/2 );
    CGContextDrawImage( context, CGRectMake( 0, 0, width, height ), originalFrame );

    CGImageRef tempDisplayImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage( context );
    [self.displayLayer performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setContents:) withObject:(id)tempDisplayImage waitUntilDone:YES];

    CGImageRelease( tempDisplayImage );
    CGContextRelease( context );
    CGColorSpaceRelease( graySpace );

    CGImageRelease( originalFrame );
```

I know that the translating, rotating, and cropping is working because the correct image is displayed in my displayLayer. Any ideas why croppedData buffer remains empty despite the context properly drawing the image?

Comment: This code doesn't call `CGBitmapContextGetData`. Please show the code that does, and especially how it relates to this code.

Comment: Check for originalFrame being nil or blank.